# SOAP Fault unexpected element but looks same

Tags: spring-boot, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

I am receiving this error.  I have seen this answered several time but in those quesitons there was a wrogn name or case issue.  This they look the same.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header />
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en">unexpected element (uri:"http://service.xxx.com/provider/aaa/bbb/2015/", local:"retrieveAccountRequest"). Expected elements are &lt;{http://service.xxx.com/provider/aaa/bbb/2015/}tns:retrieveAccountRequest&gt;</faultstring>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not notice the "tns:" on the expected elements.  It is always the stupid, careless stuff that gets you.